# How can we write a custom annotation to mask a argument in the constructor of a response pojo in maven java project

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

I want to mask mobile number present in the constructor of response pojo that prepares the response for end user to see the output messages.Is custom annotation a good way to solve this problem or is there any other better way to resolve this ?

For ex:

```
 public ResponsePojo(String mobileNumber,
            int nextRequestInterval) {
        this.message = MessageFormat.format(message, mobileNumber);
        this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
    }
```

I want to do something like below :

```
 public ResponsePojo(@MaskField String mobileNumber,
            int nextRequestInterval) {
        this.message = MessageFormat.format(message, mobileNumber);
        this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
    }
```

So that where ever i found some sensitive fields to mask, i can use my annotation @MaskField to mask some part of data in that field. Please suggest with sample code.

Comment: You could create a wrapper for your mobile number with a method to return masked string.

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit to the old, ugly formatting? The code looked much better after I edited it for you. Your extra line break in the method signature and chaotic indentation makes it less readable. Furthermore, the new style with triple backticks is now preferred on SO compared to having to indent the whole snippet by 4 spaces. I also explicitly set Java as a language, so you do not have to rely on auto-detection for syntax highlighting. The detected language can be wrong sometimes, if you only post snippets instead of full classes.

Answer (score 0):

An annotation never ever provides any functionality. An annotation only provides metadata,  which could be interpreted by an annotation processor according to the annotation. Therefore you would have to implement a custom annotation processor.

To solve your problem, you could use a String wrapper doing the masking for you. (Or you only create a single method to mask the String.)

```
public class  MaskedString{
     private final String value;
     public MaskedString(String input) {
         value = input;
     }
     public String getMaskedString(){
             return "mask-your-string-algorithm"(value);
     }
    // optional if you use the wrapper as parameter 
     public String getUnmaskedString(){
             return value;
     }
}
```

And use It within your method.

```
public ResponsePojo(String mobileNumber,
        int nextRequestInterval) {
    MaskedString maskedMobilNumber = new MaskedString(mobileNumber);
    this.message = MessageFormat.format(message, maskedMobilNumber.getMaskedString());
    this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
    // doSomething with the unmasked mobilNumber 
    ...mobileNumber...;
}
```

You could use the wrapper as parameter

```
public ResponsePojo(MaskedString maskedMobilNumber,
        int nextRequestInterval) {
    this.message = MessageFormat.format(message, maskedMobilNumber.getMaskedString());
    this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
    // doSomething with the unmasked mobilNumber 
    ...maskedMobilNumber.getUnmaskedString()...;
}
```

Comment: Actually it could have more fields to mask like email address, account number etc. so, i was looking for a custom annotation processor part to solve this problem in a more generic way.

Answer (score 0):

Because you tagged your question with *spring-aop*, I want to show an AOP solution. But you need to use native AspectJ, if you want to intercept constructors. Spring AOP can only intercept methods of Spring-managed components/beans, but no constructors.

The Spring manual explains how to set up native AspectJ via load-time weaving (LTW) in chapter ["Using AspectJ with Spring Applications"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Here is a simple [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in stand-alone AspectJ without Spring. You can simply adapt it to your situation:

**Parameter annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface MaskField {}
```

**Helper class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class MessageFormat {
  public static String format(String message, String mobileNumber) {
    return message + mobileNumber;
  }
}
```

**Response POJO + main method:**

I created your example constructor, but also two others, because we want a negative tests in order to make sure that the aspect only masks `@MaskField String` parameter, not `@MaskField` with another type or `String` without `@MaskField`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ResponsePojo {
  private static String message = "Mobile number: ";

  private String mobileNumber;
  private int nextRequestInterval;

  public ResponsePojo(@MaskField String mobileNumber, int nextRequestInterval) {
    this.mobileNumber = MessageFormat.format(message, mobileNumber);
    this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
  }

  public ResponsePojo(@MaskField int nextRequestInterval, @MaskField Properties properties) {
    this.mobileNumber = MessageFormat.format(message, "none");
    this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
  }

  public ResponsePojo(@MaskField int nextRequestInterval, String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = MessageFormat.format(message, mobileNumber);
    this.nextRequestInterval = nextRequestInterval;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ResponsePojo(" + mobileNumber + ", " + nextRequestInterval + ")";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Do not mask anything
    System.out.println(new ResponsePojo(11, new Properties()));
    System.out.println(new ResponsePojo(22, "+49 9090 87654321"));
    // Mask phone number here
    System.out.println(new ResponsePojo("+49 9090 87654321", 42));
  }
}
```

Running the program without an aspect would yield:

```
ResponsePojo(Mobile number: none, 11)
ResponsePojo(Mobile number: +49 9090 87654321, 22)
ResponsePojo(Mobile number: +49 9090 87654321, 42)
```

So far, so good. No masking, of course.

**Aspect:**

While it is easy to limit the pointcut to constructors having at least one `@MaskField String` parameter via `execution(*.new(.., @de.scrum_master.app.MaskField (String), ..))`, this will match at any parameter position and theoretically there could be multiple `@MaskField String` parameters. So we cannot simply map a single parameter to an advice method parameter. Instead, we need to iterate over the arrays of arguments and of parameter annotations at the same time and limit masking to only `@MaskField String` parameters.

We need to use an `@Around` advice, because only in this advice type we can modify the arguments array and pass it on to the called method via `proceed(args)`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.ConstructorSignature;

import de.scrum_master.app.MaskField;

@Aspect
public class MaskFieldAspect {
  @Around("execution(*.new(.., @de.scrum_master.app.MaskField (String), ..))")
  public Object maskFieldInConstructor(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    //System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);

    ConstructorSignature signature = (ConstructorSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Annotation[][] annotations = signature.getConstructor().getParameterAnnotations();
    Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      for (Annotation annotation : annotations[i]) {
        if (annotation instanceof MaskField)
          args[i] = maskPhoneNumber((String) args[i]);
      }
    }
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed(args);
  }
  
  String maskPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    return phoneNumber.replaceFirst("....$", "****");
  }
}
```

Running the program again with an the active aspect, yields:

```
ResponsePojo(Mobile number: none, 11)
ResponsePojo(Mobile number: +49 9090 87654321, 22)
ResponsePojo(Mobile number: +49 9090 8765****, 42)
```

See? For the 3rd constructor call, masking is active, but not for the 2nd one, because there the String parameter was not annotated.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the class MaskFieldAspect is not getting called at all.Could you tell me the changes required to get it called or to get a debug pointer in it ?

Comment: Then your configuration is wrong. Please do read the manual chapter I pointed you to. I wanted to help you solve your AOP problem. I cannot debug your whole application, after you shared just a tiny snippet. I can only debug what I see. Besides, there should be a little bit work left for yourself, programming is more than just copy and paste. My example code is complete.

Comment: Feedback, please. Let's get this question closed and not leave it open forever.